# C# Get Values from Dictionary array inside

Tags: c#, dictionary

So today am trying to sort out how to get array values inside dictionary based on array but its picked randomly (see code below). Hope its understandable. I can't find anything about on google and also I can't find solution by myself. For any more information to provide please comment.

Dictionary Array looks like:

```
protected Dictionary<string, int>[] quests = new[]
{
  new Dictionary<string, int>() {{ "Name", 1 }, {"Description", 1 }, {"Earn", 500 }},
  new Dictionary<string, int>() {{ "Name", 2 }, {"Description", 2 }, {"Earn", 1000 }},
  new Dictionary<string, int>() {{ "Name", 3 }, {"Description", 3 }, {"Earn", 1200 }},
  new Dictionary<string, int>() {{ "Name", 4 }, {"Description", 4 }, {"Earn", 1400 }},
  new Dictionary<string, int>() {{ "Name", 5 }, {"Description", 5 }, {"Earn", 1600 }},
  new Dictionary<string, int>() {{ "Name", 6 }, {"Description", 6 }, {"Earn", 1800 }},
  new Dictionary<string, int>() {{ "Name", 7 }, {"Description", 7 }, {"Earn", 2000 }},
  new Dictionary<string, int>() {{ "Name", 8 }, {"Description", 8 }, {"Earn", 2200 }}
};
```

so inside is another dictionary. To get random from quest dictionary am using:

```
            Random random = new Random();
            int index = random.Next(quests.Length);
```

now how do I get those values from dictionary inside quest?

Comment: Please remove the `wpf` and `xaml` tags. They don't seem to be related to your question.

Comment: var randomDictionary = quests[index];
var nameOfRandomDictionary = randomDictionary["Name"];

Comment: Why are you using `Dictionary` objects in the first place? Why haven't you declared a class named `Quest` with `Name`, `Description` and `Earn` properties and then created an array or collection of that type? That said, `Earn` is a bad name and it should probably be something like `Reward`.

Comment: @user18387401: in case of *lightweight* implementation `record` or *named* `Tuple` can be used: `(Name : 8, Description : 8, Reward : 2200)`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, given the name ("quests") I suspect that this is for a simple RPG, so a `record` might be appropriate but I don't think a `Tuple` would be.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to take the right dictionary using the `index` and than fetch your data.

Follow this example that use Linq

```
var myQuest = quests [index];
var name = myQuest.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Key == "Name").Value;
var description= myQuest.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Key == "Description").Value;
var earn= myQuest.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Key == "Earn").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

By specifying an `index` to the array, and accessing the `value` by `key` in square brackets.
Example:

```
var myQuest = quests[index];
var name = myQuest["Name"];
var description= myQuest["Description"];
var earn= myQuest["Earn"];
Console.WriteLine ("Hello Mono World:"+name+":"+description+":"+earn);
```

[Live demo](https://rextester.com/GGDG29800)

Answer (score 0):

Your example does not make too much of a sense in my opinion. The name and description should be directly connected to the dictionary entry. You just have triples of disconnected data.
If you want to have three attributes for one dictionary entry you either create a class or use tuples if you want it without any more coding:

Class

```
  Dictionary<string, MyClass>
```

Tuples

```
  Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string, int>>
```

Tuple example (class would be very similar)

```
        Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string, int>> myDic = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string, int>>();
        myDic.Add("MyItem1", new Tuple<string, string, int>("BagOfHope", "Valuable Item", 100));
        myDic.Add("MyItem2", new Tuple<string, string, int>("ShoeOfLuck", "Very Valuable Item", 200));
        myDic.Add("MyItem3", new Tuple<string, string, int>("Purse of sadness", "Trash Item", 10));
```

**Get**: Value for "MyItem2"

```
        Tuple<string, string, int> searchedItem;
        myDic.TryGetValue("MyItem2",  out searchedItem);

        int searchedvalue = searchedItem.Item3;
```

or even easier:

```
        myDic.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Key.Equals("MyItem2"));
```

**Get**: Tuple for items that have 100 in value

```
        myDic.Where(i => i.Value.Item3 == 100);
```